# Peer reviewed article not picked up by Google scholar

Tags: google-scholar

I've recently published an article in a fairly well respected journal in the Netherlands but it is not being picked up by google scholar's index.

The journal is not a 'predatory journal' and 3 of the volume's 5 articles have been picked up by google. How come mine hasnt made it?

Thanks for any advice you can spare,
Cheers!

Comment: Give it some time?

Comment: It's been a month or so already...this doesnt explain why some of the journal's contents has been picked up, but not mine.  But yes, time is a great healer :p I will get over this disappointment one day :)